# Unable to add null columns in sql query via sql developer in 12 c

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle12c

I am trying to run the query in sql developer, Oracle 12c.

```
Select id, phone_number, null as contact,null as name from emp;
```

I need to add 2 extra columns with null data for now.

The above query throws error : from keyword not found where expected.

What am i doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, because column name can't be `number` - it is reserved for **datatype**.

Rename the column to something else.

---

As you commented, column name is - actually - `phone_number`. If that's so, query works OK:

```
SQL> select * from emp;

        ID PHONE_NUMB
---------- ----------
         1 1234-5678

SQL> select id, phone_number, null as contact, null as name from emp;

        ID PHONE_NUMB C N
---------- ---------- - -
         1 1234-5678

SQL>
```

Comment: My bad, the columns are id and phone_number. I need to add contact and name as headers with null values. Even when i run Select id, phone_number, null as contact,null as name from emp; It is still throwing error.

Comment: Then you did something wrong. I added some more info into the answer; as you can see, it *works*.